# QDir::rename returns false

Tags: qt

I would like to transfer a file from a certain directory to another, But when i use QDir. rename it seems to always fail.

```
void handler::moveToTempFolder(QString localFilePath)
{

qDebug()<<localFilePath; <--- "C:/Users/user1/Pictures/IMG_00000009.jpg"

qDebug()<<"/TempFiles/" + getFileNameFromPath(localFilePath); <---- "/TempFiles/IMG_00000009.jpg" a folder that is in the same location as the .pro

QDir dir;
if(dir.rename(localFilePath,"/TempFiles/" + getFileNameFromPath(localFilePath)))
    qDebug()<<"Success";
else
    qDebug()<<"Failed";

}
```

I am getting Failed on my terminal. can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt does not have a method to access the project folder that you .pro file is in.  Probably because once you deploy this, any device other than yours will not have that folder.

It can however access the folder where the executable is with QDir::currentPath().

Also, I'm not sure how you defined getFileNameFromPath - but you can do that with QFileInfo.

```
void MainWindow::moveToTempFolder(QString localFilePath)
{
    QFileInfo fileInfo(localFilePath);

    QDir dir;
    QString tempFilePath = dir.currentPath() + "/TempFiles/" + fileInfo.fileName();

    if(dir.rename(localFilePath, tempFilePath))
    {
        qDebug() << "Success";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed";
    }

}
```

**Note:** When you run this from Qt Creator, your /TempFiles/ folder will most likely be in the same folder as your /debug/ and /release/ folders (one level up from your executable).  But once you deploy this (or run it manually from the .exe) - /TempFiles/ will be in the same folderas the .exe

Comment: currentPath solved the problem. You are actually right i did not think about that

Answer (score 1):

The working directory while the program is running is the build folder, not the project folder. My guess would be that is your problem.